# Variable increment (index++) not increase 1 each time

Tags: java

My program will read a file line by line, then split the line by delimiter | (vertical line) and stored into a String []. However, as column position and number of columns in the line will change in the future, instead of using concrete index number 0,1,2,3..., I use index++ to iterate the line split tokens;

After running the program, instead of increase 1, the index will increase more than 1 each time.

My code is like as follows:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = null;
String[] lineTokens = null;
int index = 1;
DataModel dataModel = new DataModel();
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // check Group C only
        if(line.contains("CCC")) { 
            lineTokens = line.split("\\|");
            dataModel.setGroupID(lineTokens[index++]);
            //System.out.println(index); The value of index not equal to 2 here. The value change each running time
            dataModel.setGroupName(lineTokens[index++]);
            //System.out.println(index);
            // dataModel.setOthers(lineTokens[index++]); <- if the file add columns in the middle of the line in the future, this is required.
            dataModel.setMemberID(lineTokens[index++]);
            dataModel.setMemberName(lineTokens[index++]);
            dataModel.setXXX(lineTokens[index++]);
            dataModel.setYYY(lineTokens[index++]);
            index = 1;
            //blah blah below
        }
    }
    br.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {    
}
```

The file format is like as follows:

```
Prefix | Group ID | Group Name | Memeber ID | Member Name | XXX | YYY
GroupInterface | AAA | Group A | 001 | Amy   | XXX | YYY
GroupInterface | BBB | Group B | 002 | Tom   | XXX | YYY
GroupInterface | AAA | Group A | 003 | Peter | XXX | YYY
GroupInterface | CCC | Group C | 004 | Sam   | XXX | YYY
GroupInterface | CCC | Group C | 005 | Susan | XXX | YYY
GroupInterface | DDD | Group D | 006 | Parker| XXX | YYY
```

Instead of increase 1, the index++ will increase more than 1. I wonder why this happen and how to solve it? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: *"the index++ will increase more than 1"*, no it won't. It is extremely unlikely that `index++` is broken.

Comment: Shouldn't `index` start at `0`?

Comment: You are running in a Debugger?

Comment: **Never**  write `} catch (Exception ex) {    
}`. Always handle exceptions properbly

Comment: Why are you using  **index = 1;**  within the if block.

Comment: @Jens, yes, I am running in a Debugger. Looks like debugger not increase in accordance with the sequence?

Comment: If you inspect the something that uses index++ in the line the Debugger also execute it !! be carefull

Comment: @Jens, thanks. It takes me few hours to find out this...

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Well, @SomeProgrammerDude slyly hinted it, but I'll just come out and say it:  when you reset `index` it should be set to **zero**, not 1.

By starting `index` at 1, you're always indexing one position ahead of where you should be, and you're probably eventually getting an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` that's being swallowed up by your empty `catch` clause.